# MySql Group by with Pivot

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, pivot

I am having a table in mysql (say studentinfo).

```
SELECT * FROM StudentInfo;
```

[image]

I want the following output without using any extra or temporary table. (May be using group by and pivot)

[image]

Comment: What have you tried to achieve your desired output?  Edit your question with your attempt.

Comment: I confused to combine the group by and pivot and I stuck there itself.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a pivot table, here is a [link](http://stratosprovatopoulos.com/web-development/mysql/pivot-a-table-in-mysql/) with lots of good examples.

Essentially, your just gonna do something like this

```
 SELECT Rollnumber, 
        property
      CASE WHEN Property="Name" then Property end as Name,
      CASE WHEN Property="Year" then Property end as Year,
      CASE WHEN Property="City" then Property end as City,
 FROM whatever_table
 GROUP BY Rollnumber
```

You can modify this however you want, to get the results you desire.

Answer (score 0):

This should do what you want:

```
select si.Rollnumber, 
       max(case when si.Property = 'Name' then si.Value end) as Name,
       max(case when si.Property = 'Year' then si.Value end) as Year,
       max(case when si.Property = 'City' then si.Value end) as City
from StudentInfo si
group by si.Rollnumber;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below:

```
      select * from (SELECT A.Rollnumber,if(A.Property='Name',Value,
        (select B.Value from StudentInfo B where B.Property='Name' and B.Rollnumber=A.Rollnumber LIMIT 1)) as Name,
        if(Property='Year',Value,
        (select B.Value from StudentInfo B where B.Property='Year' and B.Rollnumber=A.Rollnumber LIMIT 1)) as Year,
       if(Property='City',Value,
        (select B.Value from StudentInfo B where B.Property='City' and B.Rollnumber=A.Rollnumber LIMIT 1)) 
         as City 
         FROM StudentInfo A) Temp group by Rollnumber
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
    name.rollnumber,
    name.value AS name,
    year.value AS year,
    city.value AS city
FROM 
    StudentInfo name
    INNER JOIN StudentInfo year ON name.rollnumber = year.rollnumber
    INNER JOIN StudentInfo city ON name.rollnumber = city.rollnumber    
WHERE
    name.property = 'name' AND
    year.property = 'year' AND
    city.property = 'city' AND
```